# C like preprocessor macros in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm not really sure a good name for this question so please rename it if you can think of a better one.

In Bash I have a function that I am using to store certain functions. Consider:

```
menv_funcs=()

function menv_function {
  menv_funcs+=($1)
}
```

I am then using it in this manner:

```
menv_function fetch
function fetch {
  ...
}
```

I would like to use it like this though:

```
menv_function fetch {
  ...
}
```

Essentially I'm looking for something like the preprocessor macros in C would do but I have been unable to find a way. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you "store certain functions" like this? What is it, in your design, that makes you need this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't directly achieve this. However, I can think of two solutions that may be of interest to you.

First of all, you could just declare the functions as usual, and then obtain the list of declared functions through `declare -F`. This could be done like:

```
function fetch {
    :
}

menv_funcs=()
while IFS=$"\n" read l; do
    menv_funcs+=${l#declare -f }
done < <(declare -F)
```

Which will cause `menv_funcs[@]` to list all the functions declared at the point of calling the snippet. Of course, this may catch unwanted functions as well.

To avoid this, you may add some prefix to function names and filter the list:

```
function menv_fetch {
    :
}

menv_funcs=()
while IFS=$"\n" read l; do
    if [[ ${l} == 'declare -f menv_'* ]]; then
        menv_funcs+=${l#declare -f menv_}
    fi
done < <(declare -F)
```

---

And if you really want to achieve something like macros, you may try to play with `eval`:

```
menv_funcs=()

function menv_function {
    local name=${1}
    local body=${2}

    menv_funcs+=( ${name} )
    eval "function ${name} ${body}"
}

menv_function fetch "{
    :
}"
```

But note that you will actually need to quote the whole function body and escape everything appropriately.

Comment: In the line of prefixing function names, if a Bash array is not a requirement, `menv_funcs=$(declare -F | grep PREFIX | cut -c12-)`.

Comment: Thanks, not really what I'm looking for since escaping everything isn't an option but probably the best that can be done. I'll just leave it as I have it.